# Strange behavior assigning str.extracted values to df columns

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a df with a column "Cypher" whose unique values, for context, are

```
array(['', '2', '43', '64', '65', 'j9', 'j43', 'j65', 'j2', '/I', '7',
       '7/-', 'd6', 'ø7', 'ø2', 'd43', 'd64', 'd7', 'd7/I', 'ø65', 'ø7/I',
       '6', 'j7', 'd7/-', 'ø7/-', 'd7/VI'], dtype=object)
```

I need to compute the cyphered bass (these are music chords) out of this Cypher column. Some cyphers, as you see, have /xx, where xx will be the bass. (In the rest of the chords, the bass is cyphered in the figure, 64, 65, etc., but I deal with that later in the code.)

So, for those cyphers that include '/', I want to extract the stuff pre- and post- slash. This in fact works:

```
>>>df.Cypher.str.extract('(.*)/(.*)').dropna()
     0   1
15       I
21   7   -
30  d7   I
32  ø7   I
39  d7   -
43  ø7   -
45  d7  VI
```

gives the extraction I'm looking for. (I added dropna() only so that I could list the result, fyi)

This also works:

```
df[['Cyph', 'Bass']] = df.Cypher.str.extract('(.*)/(.*)')
```

it puts the extracted stuff in the new columns 'Cyph' and 'Bass' (and NaNs when nothing is extracted, as expected).

But if I try to overwrite 'Cypher', instead of going through the new column 'Cyph', it doesn't work:

```
df.loc[df.Cypher.str.contains('/'), ['Cypher', 'Bass']] = df.Cypher.str.extract('(.*)/(.*)')
```

just puts NaN both in Cypher and in Bass. (This last fact, that Bass itself gets NaN, is very puzzling; if it was that Cypher gets wiped, then sure, it means I can't overwrite values this way; but Bass should not pose problems).

I've tried everything: `.loc` at the right of the = sign, `'[^/]*'`, `'[^/]+'`, `'.*?'` instead of just `'.*'` in the re expression, etc.

So I'm going through the new 'Cyph' column, and then copying that into 'Cypher'.

But I'd like to understand why the difference in behavior...

Comment: Please post an example data frame and your expected results -

Answer (score 0):

For you assignment to work you would need to use the correct column names:

```
df.loc[df['Cypher'].str.contains('/'),
       ['Cypher', 'Bass']] = df['Cypher'].str.extract('(?P<Cypher>.*)/(?P<Bass>.*)')
```

Or:

```
m = df['Cypher'].str.contains('/')
df.loc[m, ['Cypher', 'Bass']] = df.loc[m, 'Cypher'].str.extract('(.*)/(.*)').to_numpy()
```

But, if I understand correctly, you could just use:

```
df[['Cypher', 'Bass']] = df['Cypher'].str.extract('([^/]*)(?:/(.*))?')
```

Or:

```
df[['Cypher', 'Bass']] = df['Cypher'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
   Cypher Bass
0          NaN
1       2  NaN
2      43  NaN
3      64  NaN
4      65  NaN
5      j9  NaN
6     j43  NaN
7     j65  NaN
8      j2  NaN
9            I
10      7  NaN
11      7    -
12     d6  NaN
13     ø7  NaN
14     ø2  NaN
15    d43  NaN
16    d64  NaN
17     d7  NaN
18     d7    I
19    ø65  NaN
20     ø7    I
21      6  NaN
22     j7  NaN
23     d7    -
24     ø7    -
25     d7   VI
```

Comment: Thanks so much, mozway. These are great suggestions, the last one is super elegant and I'll use it. 
But any insight into why the assignment works with new column names, and not with existing? Is it the .loc? If the assignment is made through .loc, do the columns on the right side need to have the same name?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, pandas aligns the right hand side when assigning several columns, so the names must match.